# install ice on by brew error

Tags: ruby, homebrew, ice

Install Ice by Homebrew,and i got some errors as follows:

➜  ~ brew install zeroc-ice/tap/ice

```
Tapping zeroc-ice/tap

Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap'...
remote: Counting objects: 21, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 7), reused 7 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap/Formula/php56-ice.rb
undefined method `assertions' for main:Object
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap/Formula/php56-ice37b0.rb
undefined method `assertions' for main:Object
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap/Formula/php70-ice.rb
undefined method `assertions' for main:Object
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap/Formula/php70-ice37b0.rb
undefined method `assertions' for main:Object
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap/Formula/php71-ice.rb
undefined method `assertions' for main:Object
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/zeroc-ice/homebrew-tap/Formula/php71-ice37b0.rb
undefined method `assertions' for main:Object
Error: Cannot tap zeroc-ice/tap: invalid syntax in tap!
```

Comment: It look like brew can not install dependencies for ice,

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this. Is Homebrew up to date? Run:

```
brew tap homebrew/php
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install zeroc-ice/tap/ice
```

If that doesn't work, what is the output of `brew config`?

Comment: Thanks! 
I solved it by run :➜  ~ sudo /usr/bin/gem uninstall minitest